# How do i execute multiple lines of PHP code in blade?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the following 2 lines of code in my blade template:

```
<p>
    <?php preg_match('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/i' , $recent->blog_content , $matches) ?>
    {!! str_limit($matches[0] , 50 , '...') !!}
</p>
```

Now how do i write the first like of code I.E. the below line of code:

```
<?php preg_match('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/i' , $recent->blog_content , $matches) ?>
```

In blade as both the below two syntaxs , outputs the result to the frontEnd instead of execute my code:

```
{{ preg_match('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/i' , $recent->blog_content , $matches) }}


{!! preg_match('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/i' , $recent->blog_content , $matches) !!}
```

Basically how do i execute multiple lines of PHP code in blade ?

Comment: i havent used this "blade" thing, but a ";" between instructions is not enought? try it.

Comment: You mean this? {{$recent->blog_content}}, {{$matches}}

Comment: It is bad idea to use php code inside blade template..
Instead you can process data into controller and then pass it to blade.
Blade is not meant to process data.

Comment: are you wanted to print both two lines or there is any condition.

Comment: @jyotimishra i would like to change this line of code `<?php preg_match('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/i' , $recent->blog_content , $matches) ?>` to blade

Comment: Why not put all such stuff into the controller instead, or into your model?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Blade @php [directive](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#raw-php) to execute a block of plain PHP within your template:

```
@php
    $counter = 1;
@endphp
```